# React-chart-js label data is returned 3 times with incorrect labels. Any fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am learning React and have set up a radar chart using chartjs. Everything seems to be working fine but for 1 thing - 3 of my 6 labels are identical:

[image: 3 'speeds']

I `console.log()`'d the data being sent to the chart and noticed the console.log appeared 3 times - one of those times with the incorrect labels.

[image]

Would anyone know why the data is being returned 3 times and why one of the sets of data is wrong? Would anyone know a fix?

My component's code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Radar } from 'react-chartjs';

const PokemonInfo=({pokemon}) => {

    const labels = pokemon.stats.map((info) => {
        return info.stat.name;
    });

    const data = pokemon.stats.map((info) => {
        return info.base_stat;
    });

    let charData = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                data: data,

            }
        ]
    }

    console.log(charData);

    return (
        <div>
            <Radar data={charData} width="300" height="250" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default PokemonInfo;
```

**EDIT with more info**

And where this component is being called:

```
const PokemonModal = ({showModal, closeModal, pokemon}) => {
    if(pokemon && Object.keys(pokemon).length !== 0) {
        return (
            <div>

        <Modal
          show={showModal}
          onHide={closeModal}
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">
              {pokemon !== null ? pokemon.species.name : 'Loading...'}
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            { 
                pokemon !== null ? 
                <PokemonInfo pokemon={pokemon} />
                : null
            }
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={closeModal}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
        </div>
        )
    }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `pokemon.stats`. It seems it has duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks @AnandUndavia, i console logged pokemon.stats and this too is being called 3 times. I can assume that with each call the labels array is given the first value from the api 3 times, which is why we're getting 'speed, speed, speed'. Questions is why?

Comment: Can you check the response of the API? If API is giving the labels three times, then there is no other way but to filter them on UI

Comment: @AnandUndavia, no the API seems to be called once and has the correct data (see https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/). I've placed console.logs where the fetch() function is being called and they only appear once. It's like the PokemonInfo class is being run 3 times

Comment: Even if the `PokemonInfo` is being called 3 times, it would not cause any issue. I feel somewhere the label `speed` is being pushed into the array by mistake.

Comment: Could this be due to the modal opening? I am not using any component lifecycle events like `componentDidUpdate`